# Why does pandoc have troubles with certain paths on cygwin?

Tags: cygwin, pandoc

I have installed pandoc.exe 2.10 with the Windows installer, and I am calling it from cygwin 3.1.6-1. Unlike most other commands, pandoc seems to have troubles with certain paths. I get an error “openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)” when the input or output file paths include one of the following:

- A `~`, e.g. `~/myfile.md`.
- A `/cygdrive`, e.g. `/cygdrive/c/Users/me/myfile.md`.
- A network drive, e.g. `//server/path/myfile.md`.

By contrast, paths that include the following work:

- A drive letter, e.g. `c:/Users/me/myfile.md`.
- Paths relative to the current directory, e.g. `./myfile.md` or simply `myfile.md`.
- Network drives with backslashes, e.g. `\\server\path\myfile.md`.

Why is that? Why is pandoc’s behaviour different from other commands?

Most Google hits for the error message relate to R Markdown. In the JDK build-dev mailing list, the problem was related to pandoc not being a native cygwin app (see [CR: 8180540: Add pandoc build fix for windows](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/build-dev/2017-May/019260.html)).

Comment: Windows programs do NOT recognize Cygwin path styles.

Comment: @matzeri: Thank you – that must be the answer (make it into an answer?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As /u/matzeri has said (thanks!), it is because Windows `pandoc` is a Windows program and does not recognize Cygwin path styles.

A reliable way to fix this might be using `cygpath` with the `--absolute` and `--mixed` flags, like so:

```
pandoc "$(cygpath -am path/to/file.md)" -o "$(cygpath -am path/to/other_file.html)"
```